# Почему домен и сайт хранят на разных хостингах?

Tags: хостинг, домен

Встречал много раз, что на одном хостинге регистрирую домены, а на других разворачивают сайт
Зачем так делают? Есть преимущества какие?

Comment: Хостинги не регистрируют домены, регистрацией доменов занимаются регистраторы доменных имён. Функции регистрации доменов, встроенные в хостингах, просто пользуются услугами одного из сторонних регистраторов (например, хостинг SpaceWeb является партнёром регистратора R01, «входящий в группу компаний RU-CENTER Group»)

Comment: А вообще лично у меня возникает противоположный вопрос: зачем привязывать домен к хостингу? На одном домене (на поддоменах) могут быть десятки разных сайтов, расположенных на разных хостингах. Может понадобиться переезжать с одного хостинга на другой. В таких условиях регистрировать домен у хостинга по-моему просто нет смысла (если нет каких-то очевидных преимуществ вроде низкой цены)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда программист создает свой крутой сайт, то он хочет, что бы его сайт могли найти. Можно конечно опубликовать IP адрес, но они имеют привычку меняться, да и не удобны для обычного пользователя. Поэтому, придумали доменные имена и специальные сервера - dns сервера, у которых, формально, хранится большая таблица соответствия имя и IP. Провайдеры интернета обычно своим пользователям присылают в настройках адрес близжайшего рекомендованого адреса dns сервера, что бы они могли пользоваться всеми прелестями интернета.

А вот сам сайт может в теории даже не знать о своем доменном имени. Ему это не будет мешать выполнять свою роботу. Но вот хранить и отдавать информацию о том, что он это он - он не может, ведь тут получается проблема курицы-яйца.

Но как dns сервера узнают о сайтах? для этого есть компании регистраторы, которые либо сами содержат такие сервера, либо заключили с другими компаниями договоры и просто вносят информацию-привязку в базу.

Некоторые большие хостинг компании предоставляют услуги по регистрации, некоторые просто выступают посредниками и тем самым создавая иллюзию, что это одно целое. Но по факту есть доменное имя с собственником, есть привязка этого имени к некому адресу и отдельно стоящий сервер (vds или просто маленький докер) на хостинге, где хранится сам сайт.